# Modify Attribute of Wicket ComponentTag Parent

Tags: css, validation, wicket

I have a Wicket Form. Within this form there are a few input tags. These input tags are put into div containers. These div containers "make" the style (i.e. they have style classes). 
I want to access this style of the div tag, if the validation of the child input fails. I tried to do this with a Behavior, but I cannot access the div tag (which would be the parent of the input tag). Any ideas how I can modify the style of the parent div tag if validation fails?

```
<div style="myStyle">
    <label>Field1</label> <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

THanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: in Wicket you can only modify the markup of a component. Of course everything on your page is the markup of a component of something or other, at worst your `Page` class.

But you definitely don't want to modify the way your page class generates its output. Which means that you have to make your containing div a component too.

```
<div wicket:id="myInputContainer">
    <label>Field1</label> <input wicket:id="myInput" type="text"/>
</div>
```

And as there's no more functionality you need the container do, in the Java code use the `WebMarkupContainer` class.

```
WebMarkupcontainer cont = new WebMarkupContainer( "myInputcontainer" );
cont.add( new Textfield( "myInput" ) );
form.add( cont );
```

And from here it's easy, you can attach your `Behavior` to the container and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: If you find yourself doing this a lot, it's a perfect opportunity for a custom Panel.  Form Elements need Labels, Fields, Validation Indicators, Styling, etc.  I have a FormComponentContainer panel that expects to have some FormComponent inside (TextField, Radio, etc) and provides all of the above.  Very useful.

Comment: Very good point. It's probably useful to write it as a generic class as well, with the parameter type being the class of the `FormComponent` contained within.