# Wicket visiblity and class toggle

Tags: java, wicket, markup

I'm learning Wicket and now I'm struggling with how to do a sidebar menu.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li><a wicket:id="linkA">A</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a wicket:id="linkB">B</a></li>
    <li><a wicket:id="linkC">C</a></li>
    <li><a wicket:id="linkD">D</a></li>
    <li><a wicket:id="linkE">E</a></li>
</ul>
```

Some links won't be visible to some users (according to the role of the user) and when I'm on the page where link goes to, I want `<li>` to have class `active` (like `linkB` has in the example). What's the Wicket way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add 'class="active"' you can simply add this to your java code:

```
if(...condition...){
  link.add(new AttributeAppender("class", "active");
}
```

To toggle visibility you can simply do this:

```
if(...condition...){
  item.setVisible(false);
}
```

where item is a WebMarkupContainer that is connected to one of the html li-tags via a wicket ID (you can also simply call link.setVisible(false), but the list bullet point would still be rendered then).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to reference the parent node in markup, so I don't have to assign wicket:ids to all <li>s?

Comment: see my comment to the next answer

Answer (score 2):

Wicket is component oriented framework, so the "Wicket-way" is by overwriting components methods. The simplest solution in your case would be to have the `li`-s as
Wicket components.

```
    // your custom method to load the user
    final IModel<User> user = getUserModel();
    final private Class<? extends WebPage> pageLinkA;

    WebMarkupContainer li = new WebMarkupContainer("linkContainerA") {

        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            boolean visible = user.getObject().hasRoleXY();
            setVisible(visible);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag t) {
            super.onComponentTag(t);
            if(getPage().getClass() == pageLinkA) {
               t.put("class", "active");
            }

        }
    }

   li.add(new BookmarkablePageLink("linkA", pageLinkA));
```

To avoid code repetition the most suitable way would be to create custom
component (extending Panel or GenericPanel) or at least to extend WebMarkupContainer.

Edit: As Tom pointed out, you can also use AttributeAppender and add it directly
in `onConfigure()` (based on  `getPage().getClass() == pageLinkA` ).
In this way overwriting of `onComponentTag` would not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, too. The follow-up question is same as for the Tom, is there a way to reference the parent node in markup, so I don't have to assign wicket:ids to all <li>s?

Comment: As far as I know (and following the Wicket guidelines), not. This question also is related to: [Modify Attribute of Wicket ComponentTag Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459481/modify-attribute-of-wicket-componenttag-parent). You are probably working with bootstrap and this will be common case, so I would definitely recommend to implement a custom component for the link.

Comment: Usually, you would not create a list manually, but use a Wicket ListView for the task. With a ListView you do not have to provide Wicket-IDs for each item, since the ListView takes care of it.

Comment: This is not quite right: You would still need to put wicket:id on the li element for the ListView and than add the Link within populateItem(...).

Comment: @Tom Thank you for poiting out ListView. The code looks much better now.